# Examples of $\mathscr{L}$ structure

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Let,
$$\mathscr{L}_{\text{group}}=(G,·,^{-1})$$
Be a $\mathscr{L}$- group structure.

(1)Can we have any group structure $\mathscr{L}$- group  whose language is not the language of groups?

Comment: How are you defining an $\mathscr{L}$-group, if not as a group structure that uses the language of groups?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you spell out exactly what you are looking for? And/or write some (analogous) example that you have in mind.